# Node.js to many files open - LIMIT

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu

My my part of code, return error: limit files open.
[image]

My part of code:

```
const stats = (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    req.url = (req.url === '/') ? '/index.html' : req.url;
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/web' + req.url, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(301, {
                'Location': 'https://' + conf.domain
            });
            res.end();
        } else {
            if (!req.url.match(/\.wasm$/) && !req.url.match(/\.mem$/)) {
                buf = buf.toString().replace(/%domain%/g, conf.domain);
                if (req.url.match(/\.js$/)) {
                    var randKey = rand(32);
                    tmp = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/tmpl.aes.min.js', 'utf8');
                    tmp = tmp.replace(/%aes_file%/g, enAES(randKey, buf));
                    tmp = tmp.replace(/%aes_key%/g, randKey);
                    buf = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ka-lib.min.js', 'utf8');
                    buf += tmp;
                    res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/javascript');
                }
            } else {
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
            }
            res.end(buf);
        }
    });
}

//ssl support
if (ssl) {
    var web = https.createServer({
        key: fs.readFileSync(conf.key),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(conf.cert)
    }, stats)
} else {
    var web = http.createServer(stats);
}
```

In my opinion, error is generated when fs.readFile is execute every user req?
Could someone point me better solution or maybe I wrong?

Comment: Open less files?

Comment: I need to open as less files as possible.

Comment: Not a solution, but could you try monitoring the open file handles of your node process to see if there is something suspicious . Try using: `lsof -a -p (node PID)`
Also check if the amount reduces, once there are no client request. Maybe you will find a leak here.